# meaning of 'political valence'

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [a webpage](https://misinforeview.hks.harvard.edu/article/right-and-left-partisanship-predicts-asymmetric-vulnerability-to-misinformation/).

> We quantified political partisanship based on the **political
> valence** of the news sources shared by each user.

As far as I know, 'valence' is a term used in chemistry.

I wonder what 'political valence' means in the above context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valence politics, also known as competence voting, is a model of voting behaviour that emphasises that individuals vote based upon "people's judgements of the overall competence of the rival political parties".

It basically means in this context how people "judge" the new sources shared by the users (sort of like judging based on quality).

Source from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_politics)

Or if you want to look at [Valence issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_issue)